# Visual Studio Code - плагин live server не отображается

Tags: visual-studio-code

Скачать плагин Live Server для VS Code, но этот плагин не отображается не снизу в панели, ни когда нажимаешь пкм по файлу в контекстном меню. Подскажите, в чем проблема?

Answer (score 2):

пкм на экране с кодом, там есть Open with Live Server (<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>). И файл должен обязательно открываться из папки (любой), т.е. Файл->Открыть папку и ок (он откроет всю папку и выберете нужный для просмотра и запуска файл)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]